# Target DOM elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-traversal

I have the following html

```
<ul id="some_nav">
   <p>Tester</p>
</ul>
<div class="packs"></div>

<ul id="some_nav">
    <p>Jones</p>
</ul>
<div class="packs"></div>

<ul id="some_nav">
    <p>Trey</p>
</ul>
<div class="packs"></div>
```

I was wondering how I could target the class `.packs` that comes after the `<p>Jones</p>`

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique in HTML.

Comment: [please show what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). If you have even glanced at the jQuery api you'd know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should arrange your DOM structure but here you go:

```
$("p:contains('Jones')").parent().next();
```

First this selects all `p` elements that have the text `Jones`, then it goes up to its parent and then select the next sibling of each result.

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gGm4A/)**

**Reference**

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

http://api.jquery.com/next/